# Cannot Find COLLADA Headers

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install ROS Groovy on a Lenovo X200 Tablet with openSUSE 12.3. I've installed COLLADA-DOM 2.4, and it installed its headers to /usr/local/include/collada-dom2.4/. I have double and triple-checked, and dae.h is in that folder. However, when I try to run the full desktop install with:

```
sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install-space /opt/ros/groovy --install -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF
```

I get the following error:

```
    [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/src/collada_parser.cpp.o
/home/abouchard/ros_catkin_ws/src/collada_parser/src/collada_parser.cpp:45:17: fatal error: dae.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/src/collada_parser.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 717, in build_workspace_isolated
    number=index + 1, of=len(ordered_packages)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 497, in build_package
    install, force_cmake, quiet, last_env, cmake_args, make_args + catkin_make_args
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 353, in build_catkin_package
    run_command(make_cmd, build_dir, quiet)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 198, in run_command
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, ' '.join(cmd))
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/ros/groovy/env.sh make -j2 -l2' returned non-zero exit status 2
<== Failed to process package 'collada_parser': 
  Command '/opt/ros/groovy/env.sh make -j2 -l2' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> /opt/ros/groovy/env.sh make -j2 -l2

Command failed, exiting.
```

I was thinking that perhaps this was related to the cmake command, and indeed there is no FindCOLLADA_DOM.cmake file on the computer, but I found one online and put it in /usr/share/cmake/Modules to no avail. I'm still digging into the cmake documentation to see if I can find any error either in the CMakeLists for collada_parser in ROS or the FindCOLLADA_DOM.cmake script, but I don't seem to be making any headway.

Has anyone else run into this that could perhaps give me some pointers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66537/cannot-find-collada-headers/) by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 320 on 2013-07-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Chalk this one up to a mystery - I uninstalled everything collada from my system, tried again, and it seems to have worked. Go figure.

---

Originally posted by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) with karma: 320 on 2013-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0